# Searching sample distribution with given parameteres

Tags: statistics, simulation, moment-problem

I have a very simple question, but it is hard, at least to me, for giving a solution.

Given values of mean, variance and median, can you find a method to generate a random sample with these parameters?

For example, mean = 2, var = 20 and median = 4

I'm searching for any type of distribution: discrete or continous.

What do you think?

Comment: If $P(X=4)=\frac56$ and $P(X=-8)=\frac16$ then I think you get those values